Manga where the main character gets experimented on by succubus
The main character, along with a few other people, are kept in a lab by succubus and experimented on.
Later on the main character discovers the truth of the lab, and tries to save his friends, then he gains the power of succubus after falling on and being absorbed by an egg.

This is Lili-Men.

A race of "succubus" that breeds human beings in the nursery, and human beings trying to eradicate them. After an eternity of time has passed since the two incompatible races began to fight, a "king" will be born who will end the battle.

The opening chapter shows a large number of humans in a "hospital" undergoing various tests. The rationale given for the tests is that the people are weak, and the tests and experiments are to make them stronger.

The actual purpose is a human farm. The nurses and doctors are part of a race of succubi that need humans to reproduce. Rather than using the traditional method, they breed humans and forcibly lay parasitic eggs that will consume the host.

The main character and his immediate "group" plan to escape from the hospital. As a result, his friends are killed and he is nearly killed and absorbed by an egg. He re-emerges from the egg with super strength and uses it to kill one of the succubi doctors.
